# Two way binding is not working in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm implementing a directive in such a way that it is accessible in multiple pages. My requirement is that when I hold down any key (as of now) I need to show the password. The password details will be coming from controller. I need to update the password in the directive.

On keydown event I want to show the password as hello and on keyup i want to show the password as `********`.

Below is the code for that:

#### HTML View

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
   <a class="f-mrgn-left-4px" 
      key-hold 
      password="statusMessage" 
      generatedpassword="selfgeneratedpassword" 
      tabindex="0" 
      ng-mousedown="ShowPassword()" 
      ng-mouseup="HidePassword()">Show</a>
   <span>{{selfgeneratedpassword}}</span>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = '******';
    $scope.statusMessage = "Password";

    $scope.ShowPassword = function () {
    console.log('show passwo', $scope.statusMessage);
        $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = $scope.statusMessage;
    }

    $scope.HidePassword = function () {
      $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = "********";
    }
}

angular.module('myApp', []).directive('keyHold', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'password': '=',
            'generatedpassword': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log('self generated password', scope.password,scope.generatedpassword, element);               
          element.bind('keydown', function () {           
            $timeout(function () {
                console.log('after timeout');
                scope.selfgeneratedpassword = scope.password;
            }, 100);
          });

          element.bind('keyup', function () {
             scope.generatedpassword = "*******";
          });
        }
    }
```

Attached fiddler will explain how I'm implementing it. [Fiddler Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Naidu526/6HcGS/1364/). In the fiddler i am unable to get the two way binding working. Can anybody help me on this. I lost a day working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ng-mousedown` or `ng-mouseup` in AngularJS 1.0.x because its not implement in this version. Just switch to AngularJS 1.4.x or higher to make it work like in this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdput9xz/)**.

Switch to the latest version of AngularJS -> https://github.com/angular/angular.js/releases

#### View

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a class="f-mrgn-left-4px" 
     tabindex="0" 
     ng-mousedown="ShowPassword()" 
     ng-mouseup="HidePassword()">Show</a>
  <span>{{selfgeneratedpassword}}</span>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = '******';
  $scope.statusMessage = "Password";

  $scope.ShowPassword = function() {
    $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = $scope.statusMessage;
  }

  $scope.HidePassword = function() {
    $scope.selfgeneratedpassword = "********";
  }
});
```

---

## Update

Now, if you click the "Show" element once (a click does set it active so it can listen to "keyup" and keydown" event) and you press a key the password will be diplayed for 1 seconds like in this **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwr3aev1/)**. The logic is now placed in a directive:

#### View

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a class="f-mrgn-left-4px" tabindex="0" 
      key-hold 
      password="statusMessage" 
      generatedpassword="generatedpassword">Show</a>
  <span>{{generatedpassword}}</span>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.generatedpassword = '******';
  $scope.statusMessage = "Password";
});

myApp.directive('keyHold', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'password': '=',
      'generatedpassword': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('keydown', function() {
          scope.generatedpassword = scope.password;
          scope.$apply();
      });

      element.bind('keyup', function() {
       $timeout(function () {
          scope.generatedpassword = "*******";
          scope.$apply();
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, My question is not about ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup. It is about when we had focus on the button and keydown i want to show the password that should happen on the directive but not on the controller part. Thanks for you help

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu mhm, so why did you add this logic in your controller too?

Comment: sorry about that, but just wanted to show that this is happening and i want that. Somehow missed it.

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu ok please wait, Going to make it work in your directive.

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu you want to diplay the clear password for 100ms when a key was pressed?

Comment: yes, on key down press for some time let's say 1sec then i should show the clear password.

Comment: in my project it is not working, but i will work some more time on that.

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu great. Compare my solution carefully with your project to make it work. You can make it =) !